# How can I get the PSK on android with xamarin in C#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, networking

I'm making a tool for testing network security.

But I'm clueless how can I get the PSK of a wpa2-psk network.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to retrieve the PSK from a network that has been configured on the device.

You can't.

Just getting the list of [configured networks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#getConfiguredNetworks()) is deprecated.

Even for privileged applications, the API specifies that only a subset of the information is retrieved.